# All formula fields are not retrieved in object metadata

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, eclipse

I have retrieved Object metadata in Eclips.
However some Formula fields are not showing in object metadata.
Is there any way to fetch all formula fields for all objects available in sales-force org.

Comment: How to retrieved Managed object metadata in Eclips.                                   <types>
        <members>Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types  But,Its not working

Answer (score 0):

All formula fields are coming under Object Metadata